# Why would Spring Boot not give an error for bad environment variable syntax in a configuration file

Tags: spring-boot

I accidentally added the following to my application.properties which causes Spring Boot to not start and also not give any errors.

**See referenced Sample Project below:**

To recreate the problem add the bad config line to an application.properties file

Run as a spring boot app (I was doing the Spring Tools Suite method of yourSpringBootProject > Run As > Spring Boot App)

Watch how it does not start and gives no errors as to a cause.

The mistake, I was attempting to add a hostname environment variable to a log file and did it the wrong way.

```
#The wrong way and big silent time wasting boom!!!
logging.file=logs/springBootApp{$HOSTNAME}.log
#What I wanted to do and not blow the thing up...
#logging.file=logs/springBootApp${HOSTNAME}.log
```

As noted above I did the environment variable incorrectly the first time, and it caused Spring Boot to not start and give off no errors, which is easy to see here but in a complex config it was a world of pain. [demoConfigFail github example to try and run this mistake in a project for debugging](https://github.com/djbrieck/demoConfigFail)

Anyways to me it seems like Spring Boot should have given off some kind of error. Trying to figure out why no errors for this simple mistake.

Comment: you should post the output of the server that fails to start but doesn't show the error.

Comment: You can run it locally in Spring Tools Suite  as noted in the example demoConfigFail project, either way there is no console output. And no log file gets written.